# Force HTTPS to all except sub-domains and folders

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would want to force HTTPS for entire website except:

1. Subdomains
2. One Directory

For, one directory named efr I have done something as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !efr [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And now condition for sub-domain is remaining. I want to stop HTTPS for:
sub-domain.domain.com and only domain.com should be HTTPS.

Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another condition to make sure this rule is applied for main domain only:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^efr https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: 2nd line- I would want for www.domain.com and domain.com, both. Will it take care?

Comment: Yes `^(www\.)?domain\.com$` matches both www and non-www

Comment: It is not working :( Here is the file content-
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !efr [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^wfr https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]

Comment: This is probably not the site you are looking for! Exception

Comment: You need to replace you current rule with this. You still have it in your code.

Comment: Then what about efr directory?

Comment: Start reading code carefully. I already have it covered using `RewriteRule !^efr`

Comment: Thats efr and you wrote wfr.. Let me check

Comment: Yes that's a typo mistake fixed.

Comment: Change `domaon.com` to your actual domain and test in a new browser, rule is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes it worked with new browser. Thanks! What if I have more than one directory and more sub-domains?

Comment: This condition will exclude all sub domain since it matches only primary domain. To exclude more directories use: `RewriteRule !^(efr|abc|pqr) ...` rule.

Comment: Hi, I also wanted to stop by keyword. For eg. if the keyword in URL is  'contact', HTTPS should not be applied on it. How can I do so?

Comment: You can use `RewriteRule` as: **`RewriteRule !(efr|contact) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]`**